# Pandas groupby on membership of a set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a large pandas dataframe which stores key, value pairs, a primary group and a set of secondary groups.

```
key    |  value  |  primary_group  | secondary_groups
height    10        1                set(["B","C"])
width     9         1                set(["A","C"])
width     9         2                set(["B","A"])
etc.
```

**I want to get the mean value for each key, for each secondary group.**

This would be simple if using the primary group:

```
df.groupby(["key","primary_group"]).mean()
```

But for the secondary group I'm stumped - the easiest way seems to be to normalise it and repeat each row for each secondary group:

```
key    |  value  |  primary_group  | secondary_group
height    10        1                B
height    10        1                C
width     9         1                A
width     9         1                C
width     9         2                B
width     9         2                A

df.groupby(["key","secondary_group"]).mean()
```

But this seems like a very wasteful way to do it - I'm not sure my data would end up fitting in memory in that format.

Comment: You could create additional columns instead of additional rows, then your data would almost certainly fit into memory. Then groupby each added column separately (but getting sum and count, not mean), and add the resulting dataframes together.